# Нормы управления

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каких словосочетаних нарушены нормы управления?
**1) Из около трех тысяч;

2) Сделал наперекор распоряжению;

3) Вернулся из концерта;

4) Работать в огороде;

5) Удивился находчивости ;**

Answer (score 1):

Неправильно построена только первая фраза. Предлог **около** оказался рядом с предлогом **из**. Это неблагозвучно.

"В концерт" и "на концерт" - равноправные варианты, значит, можно сказать"из концерта": [концерт:  в концерте и на концерте  (быть), См. в - на, п. 2в](http://www.interword.se/Syntax/Lektionsmaterial/Rozenthal_Rektion.pdf). Справедливости ради надо сказать, что так уже мало кто говорит. ***Тут же, выходя из концерта, разгоряченный, он сильно простудился и уже на другой день слег в постель. [С. А. Базунов]***
***По возвращении из концерта, когда мы ложились спать и Анюта уже собиралась задуть свечу, я не выдержала и, не глядя на нее, спросила: [С. В. Ковалевская]***

Answer (score 0):

Первое и третье. Сами послушайте, не звучит ведь!

Comment: Не звучит. Ну а почему?

Comment: Предлоги антонимы: В - ИЗ, НА - С . В школу - из школы, на концерт - с концерта.